# Difference in meaning between "Into the house leap the children" and "The children leap into the house

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "Into the house leap the children" and "The children leap into the house" ?

I have learned that "Into the house leap the children" mean "The children leap into the house".

By the way, if it were interpreted in English order, i suddenly think that the meaning of each other seems to be slightly different.

Does "Into the house leap the children" mean "The children walk into the house before the children leap" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there is no difference in meaning between the two constructions.

But there’s a huge difference in idiomatic use; that’s to say, the way people speak.

If the children were leaping into the house - a slightly unusual way of putting things - we would expect someone to say: **The children are leaping into the house**.

If the children, for example, leap into the house after swimming or some event, we might say: **The children leap into the house (after swimming)**

If someone said: **Into the house the children leap**, we would understand the sentence. It’s grammatically correct but it’s not idiomatic. So it would puzzle a listener.

However it would make complete sense as part of a poem because it shows people why you have used that unusual construction: **Laughing out loud, their towels in a heap, into the house the children leap.**